# Xtext outline view using grammar and Xtend

Tags: grammar, xtext, xtend

How to get outline view in **Xtext** using **Xtend** for this particular parser rule written in Xtext?

```
def_slotted_exemplar:   
       ex= Exemplar (':'name=ID )
        ','
    (   '{}' |( ('{}'',') ('{}' | inht=Inherit | val=inherit_validation))|
        ('{' ('}' | ( ('}'',')
        ('{}' | inht=Inherit | val=inherit_validation)))) |
        ('{' ((cls=classvariable) | (val=def_validation)) ('}' | ( ('}'',')
        ('{}' | inht=Inherit | val=inherit_validation))))                  
    )

    ')'
    '$'
    ;
```

Comment: what is your expected outline view. what is your impl so far?

Comment: i have class and methods written in Xtext grammar above code is an one of my parser rules

Comment: Implement the outlinetreeprovider. I can't give you any hints if you don't provide anything

Comment: how to implement outline tree provider in it                                              
class MagikOutlineTreeProvider extends DefaultOutlineTreeProvider {